# Passing Object from a table row to bootstrap modal

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, bootstrap-modal

I'm trying to put to a modal the attributes of a clicked table row. I am using angularjs. Nothing happens in my code:
Basically this is my html code like below:

```
<tr ng-repeat="pokemons in pokemon">
    <td>{{pokemons.pokemon_number}}</td>
    <td><a href="javascript:;" ng-click="getDetails(pokemons)" id="clickable">{{pokemons.pokemon_name}}</a></td>
    <td>{{pokemons.type1}}</td>
    <td>{{pokemons.type2}}</td>
</tr>
```

Then this is in my script tag:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [])
myApp.controller('SimpleController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.findPokemon = function(filterKey){
        $http.get('pokemon/search-by-name/' + filterKey).then(function(response) {
            $scope.pokemon = response.data
        })
    } 
    $scope.getDetails = function(pokemons){
        $scope.pokemonDetails = pokemons
        $('#viewModal').modal('show');
    } 
}]) `
```

Modal:

```
    <div id="pokemon-zoom" class="modal">
        <div class="modal-content animate">
            <div class="imgcontainer">
                <span onclick="document.getElementById('pokemon-zoom').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-container">
                <img id="pokemon-image" src="Bulbasaur.jpg" height="200px" width="200px">
                <div class="pokemon-details">
                    <h1>Pokemon Data</h1>
                    <div id="pokemon-data-text">
                        <p>Pokemon no: {{pokemonDetails.pokemon_number}}</p>
                        <p>Type1: {{pokemonDetails.type1}}</p>
                        <p>Type2: {{pokemonDetails.type12}}</p>
                        <p></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="options">
                    <button class="options-link" href="#">Edit</a>
                    <button class="options-link" href="#">Delete</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Btw some parts there seem unnecessary i just included them

Comment: where is the code for your modal?

Comment: @Aravind i added it already. Sorry this is my first time

Comment: Are you available in tv?

Comment: @Aravind unfortunately i'm not

Comment: There are couple of reasons for this not displaying. I have faced this in my application. That's why directly I can  solve. Any other alternative?

Comment: @Aravind request sent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer for your problem

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr ng-repeat="pokemons in pokemon">
            <td>{{pokemons.pokemon_number}}</td>
            <td>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" 
                  style="width:100px; height:25px"
                  ng-click="openModal(pokemons)"
                  data-toggle="modal" data-target="#pokemon-zoom" >
                    {{pokemons.pokemon_name}}</button>
              </td>
            <td>{{pokemons.type1}}</td>
            <td>{{pokemons.type2}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Modal Code is this

```
<div id="pokemon-zoom" class="modal">
    <div class="modal-content animate">
        <div class="imgcontainer">
            <span onclick="document.getElementById('pokemon-zoom').style.display='none'" class="close" title="Close Modal">&times;</span>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-container">
            <img id="pokemon-image" src="Bulbasaur.jpg" height="200px" width="200px">
            <div class="pokemon-details">
                <h1>Pokemon Data of</h1>
                <div id="pokemon-data-text">
                    <p>Pokemon no: {{selected_pokemon.pokemon_number}}</p>
                    <p>Type1: {{selected_pokemon.type1}}</p>
                    <p>Type2: {{selected_pokemon.type12}}</p>
                    <p></p>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="options">
                <button class="options-link" href="#">Edit</button>
                <button class="options-link" href="#">Delete</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

your controller will be having a method with name openModal

```
  $scope.openModal=function (ob){
      $scope.selected_pokemon=ob;
  }
```

Here is a [LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/xcX49RhqzIj1DZ12B9Pl)

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to show the modal by calling `$('#viewModal').modal('show');`, but your modal has id `pokemon-zoom`. Show the modal by calling `$('#pokemon-zoom').modal('show');`

Make sure the modal is defined within the scope of the Controller `SimpleController` so that it can access `pokemonDetails`!